# how to add, edit, delete and queries since other computer (with internet)

Tags: c#

this is my connection class, i know i am going to put the ip, or i am in a error ? the direction of internet? what do i go to put? can i do it with web service? what is the form easy for to do it?  here my connection class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MisNotas.Conexiones
{
    class Conexion
    {
        public SqlConnection conectar()
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=misnotas;Integrated Security=True");
            return con;
        }

        public void EjecutarConsulta(SqlCommand comando)
        {
            comando.Connection.Open(); // open connection
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); // execute the query
            comando.Connection.Close(); // close the connection



        }



    }
}
```

The idea is since another place, i can to start session and to do queries and edits... how to do it?

it is in windows application not in asp.net.. thanks

i will put diferents tags for the import is how to do it... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the question is how to access a database on a different machine, if that is the case - you can specifiy the IP address or name of the remote machine in the connection string:

```
public SqlConnection Conectar(string remoteMachine)
{
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0}\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=misnotas;Integrated Security=True", remoteMachine));
      return con;
}
```

Note however you still have to figure out security, i.e. integrated security might not work remotely - for a full list of the options with examples check out this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: @BrokenGlass I've never do it, is remoteMachine a direction ip?

Comment: @angel: its' a machine name or an IP address, i.e. "127.0.0.1" or "ANGELPC", of course the machine name must resolve to be useful

Comment: @BrokenGlass mmm but i feel i need something more, we imagine i have my database in my house and i have my program in a usb, i go to a ciber for (do a query for example) i plug my usb i open my program (with your connetion) and is it going to work? (always and when my computer (from my house) is turn on)???

Comment: @angel: If the IP address is correct I don't see why it wouldn't (provided the credentials are also correct, see connection string examples)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Also, the IP address has to be public and behind firewall (or the firewall has to be configured properly).

Comment: @svick: Yes of course the IP address must be reachable and the SQL server port must be opened to the outside and SQL must accept remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about the database connection string?

"server=123.123.123.123;database=database_name;user=user_name;password=password"

That is the basic that works for just about any ADO accessible database, but of course, if you are accessing a server where the Windows NTLM mechanism such that the user identity under which your software is a user for that database can work, Integrated Security = true is best.